# Finding IP address for Zebra LP2844-Z USB

Tags: zebra-printers

Trying to find the IP address of my Zebra LP2844-Z USB connected printer.

Need to print from my android APP using labelworks SDK.

I need the IP and Port for my printer.

What is the best way to get this?

Thanks

Comment: Does your printer have a ethernet port or only usb? If you have only usb, the printer won't have an ipaddress. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

**If your model comes with ethernet connection:**
On the back of the printer, next to the ethernet connection there should be a small button. Press this and the printer gives you a label shoving existing network configuration.

When you have the ip you can access settings in web gui using this IP as address.

**Else if your model is using USB only:**
You would have to set up the printer on a PC (or other usb printer hosting capable device) and share the printer on the network. Then the printer ip, or address on the network is \\computername/ip\printername/port

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Zebra Setup Utility (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/desktop/lp-2844-z.html). Use the Open Communications With Printer option to send the command:

```
! U1 getvar "ip.addr"
```

Make sure you end the command with an Enter (CRLF) or the printer will not respond.

The IP address should be displayed in the results window, below the command window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have just tried your suggestion, but nothing seems to be happening, and there is no result back from the printer.

Comment: It looks like your printer is ELP compatible - https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7922. Download the the EPL programming guide. It has the correct Set-Get-Do commands for your printer.

Answer (score 0):

As Russel suggests, ust the [Zebra Setup Utility](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/zebralink/zebra-setup-utility.html) to "Open Communications with Printer".  Type:

```
~WC
```

The printer will print a network configuration label with it's IP address and other network information.  The default port is 9100.
The printer is too old a model to support the command Russel suggested although it works on most newer Zebra printers.

Comment: This utility is only windows or android so does not provide a device agnostic result.